# Firebase Simple Login with twitter OAuth

Tags: angularjs, firebase, twitter-oauth, angularfire, firebasesimplelogin

I'm trying to implement twitter login in my angularfire application, and can't seem to figure it out. I've set my callback URL to https://auth.firebase.com/v2/MyFIREBASE/auth/twitter/callback, and the app does display a popup that hangs for about 3 seconds. The URL on the popup is https://auth.firebase.com/v2/MyFIREBASE/auth/twitter/callback.

In my code, I have copy and pasted directly from the angularfire auth section.

#### HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="SampleCtrl">
  <div ng-show="auth.user">
    <p>Hello, {{auth.user.displayName}}</p>
    <button ng-click="auth.$logout()">Logout</button>
  </div>
  <div ng-hide="auth.user">
    <p>Welcome, please log in.</p>
    <button ng-click="auth.$login('twitter')">Login</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
app.factory("simpleLogin",
  ["$firebaseSimpleLogin", function($firebaseSimpleLogin) {
    var ref = new Firebase("https://MyFIREBASE.firebaseio.com/");
    return $firebaseSimpleLogin(ref);
  }]
);
app.controller("SampleCtrl", 
  ["$scope", "simpleLogin", function($scope, simpleLogin) {
    $scope.auth = simpleLogin;
  }]
);
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there's a version mismatch at play here - the callback URL you're using is for a more recent version of the Firebase web client (>= v1.1.0) than is currently bundled with AngularFire (which uses the older, deprecated Firebase Simple Login client). A new version of AngularFire will be released soon which supports the newer API.

In the meantime, you can either skip the AngularFire factory methods and call into the Firebase client directly (i.e. `ref.authWithOAuthPopup('twitter', ...)`) with the Firebase web client >= v1.1.0 *or* use the older version with Firebase Simple Login, and an old-format callback URL, documented at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-simple-login/tree/master/docs/v1.